# ES6 Angular1 service syntax, how to create a service and use it?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-services

I know there are similar questions, but somehow they all have different code and i cant seem to find something that answers my specific problem, im sorry.

Im following several exmaples, and i got here:

This is my soon-to-be map service (maps.service.js):

```
import angular from 'angular'
import angularConfig from '../angularConfig/angularConfig'

export default class Maps {
  initializeMap (element, options){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      return resolve(new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), options))
    })
  }
}

Maps.$inject = ['$http']

angular.module(Maps, [])
  .service('maps.service', Maps)
```

You can see its a simple class with a method inside.
At the bottom based on several examples i placed a call to angular.service, gave it a name and used the class i created. I think this is wrong, but i dont know why. I also dont know if thats the correct way to inject a service i need from angular into it.

Then, in order to consume this service i have a small controller (catalog.controller.js):

```
// import mapService from '../../common/maps/maps.service'

class catalogController {
  constructor($scope, mapsService) {
    this.$scope = $scope    
  }

  $onInit () {
    // map init

    mapService.initializeMap(param1, param2)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('it worked!!')
    })
  }
}

catalogController.$inject = ['$scope']

export default catalogController;
```

The problem is no matter how i write the code in the service, i always end up with an error when i try to use it, when i inspect mapService to see what i has inside, the function is not there.
I tried importing it and passing it as a parameter to the constructor, i tried with different ways i found to create the service, but i cant make it work, everyone seems to be using something different.

Both this files are inside a folder named 'catalog', outside this folder i have this file:

```
import angular from 'angular'
import catalog from './catalog/catalog'

let componentModule = angular.module('app.components', [
  catalog
])
.name

export default componentModule
```

which is in turn used by another file. This whole structure works, as i have things working already with controllers and views. My only problem is how to create and use a service.
Any help will be appreciated, as i have already spent many days on this!
I can provide more details if needed.
Thank you :)

Comment: It's `this.mapService = mapService` in controller constructor and `this.mapService` in other methods (not just `mapService` as you are trying to do - it's undefined). It's really not clear what the question is. ES6 is still JS, and classes are syntactic sugar for constructor functions. It isn't some sort of black magic. If you have problems with classes, try to implement this with constructor functions first. 'end up with an error' - what error? Should we guess?

Answer (score 0):

According to DI, do some changes:

Maps Service:

```
import angular from 'angular'
import angularConfig from '../angularConfig/angularConfig'

export default class Maps {
  constructor($http){}

  initializeMap (element, options){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      return resolve(new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), options))
    })
  }
}

Maps.$inject = ['$http']

angular.module(Maps, [])
  .service('maps.service', Maps)
```

catalogController

```
class catalogController {
  constructor($scope, mapsService) {}

  $onInit () {
    // map init

    this.mapService.initializeMap(param1, param2)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('it worked!!')
      })
  }
}

catalogController.$inject = ['$scope', 'mapsService']

export default catalogController;
```

PS: Here is a good example: https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-angular1

Comment: thanks, i did these changes, and got an error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.common due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function Maps() due to:
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

i added 
angular.module('app.common', [])
  .service('mapsService', Maps)

to maps service and this to the controller
catalogController.$inject = ['$scope', 'mapsService']

i have a file where i import all the controllers, when i add the serv there i get it

Comment: either i get this error, or one where the service cannot be found, i searched the errors, but im pretty lost here, i think the whole problem is dependency injection right?